# Persisting to a H2 in-mem database on Openshift

Tags: playframework-2.0, h2, openshift

I have created an openshift do-it-yourself cartridge and deployed an empty play 2.1.1 framework template (from [opensas on github](https://github.com/opensas/play2-openshift-quickstart)) app there. The app ran perfectly, so I proceeded to build a simple persistence layer based on EBeans persisting to a H2 in memory database. On my local development box the play app compiles and runs fine, so I deployed it to openshift.

In my configuration files for openshift production deployment I enabled the option to perform database evolutions at system restart/deployment as opensas recommends it.

> On development mode, play will ask you to run pending evolutions to database, but when in prod mode, you have to specify it form the command line. Let's configure play to automatically apply evolutions. Edit the file conf/openshift.conf like this:

```
# openshift action_hooks scripts configuration
# ~~~~~
openshift.play.params="-DapplyEvolutions.default=true"
```

After deployment, I only get a maintenance page for my app. It looks like either it is not possible to run a h2 in-mem database on openshift or the database evolution script is not executed automatically as it should.

It should be possible to migrate the app to a postgres database (postgres cartridge in openshift), but for this app, I would like to keep things as simple as possible on a very minimalistic software stack.

Anybody done H2 on openshift before?

Comment: I am no SME on this but we do have a user who got it working. Check this forum thread out: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/unable-to-connect-to-an-h2-database

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your action_hook is executable (chmod +x), and that it is actually running by having it write a test file in your $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, just to make sure.

Comment: Thanks for that hint...I've just stopped working on my first play/openshift project at the moment, but I'll try this as soon as possible, and for sure, then will upvote your answer.